# Aggregate like Initialization without superfluous calls of constructors

Tags: c++, c++14, aggregate-initialization

I am trying to write mostly a reimplementation of `std::array`. But, I am not very happy about the rules for aggregate initialization (and some other minor details) and thus do not want to use it.

Things I do not like with aggregate initilization:

- Having less than the necessary elements in the list, produces no error, this is particularly strange for aggregates of aggregates, e.g.

  ```cpp
  struct A { int x,y; };
  std::array< A, 2 > arr{1,2,3};
  // produces A[0].x = 1, A[0].y = 2, A[1].x = 1, A[1].y = 0
  ```
- private/deleted ctors are still callable by the user

  ```cpp
  class B { B() = delete; };
  B{};  // no compile time error
  ```

What I have so far is the following:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template< typename T, typename ... Ts >
inline constexpr bool areT_v = std::conjunction_v< std::is_same<T, Ts> ... >;  

namespace ttt {
    template< typename T, int N >
    struct array
    {
        template< typename ... L > 
        array( L && ... lst ) : content{ std::forward< L >( lst ) ... } {
            static_assert( sizeof...(L) == N || sizeof...(L)==0, ""  );
            static_assert( areT_v<T,L...>, "" );
        }
        array() = default;  // not sure whether I need this one
    
        using ContentType = typename std::conditional< N>=1 , T, char >::type;
        ContentType content[ N>=1 ? N : 1];

        /* member functions */
    };
}
```

Actually I am quite happy with this implementation, apart from the following fact. Using
`ttt::array` I have more ctor calls then when using `std::array`. E.g.:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct CLASS {
    int x, y;
    CLASS() { 
        std::cout << "def-ctor" << std::endl; 
    }
    CLASS(int x_,int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) { 
        std::cout << "xy-ctor" << std::endl; 
    }
    CLASS( CLASS const & other ) : x(other.x), y(other.y) {
        std::cout << "copy-ctor" << std::endl; 
    }
};

int main() {
    std::array< CLASS, 1 > stda{CLASS{1,2}};  // calls xy-ctor
    ttt::array< CLASS, 1 > ttta{CLASS{1,2}};  // calls xy-ctor AND copy-ctor
}
```

This seems to be connected with the reason that `std::array` is aggregate initialized (because it is an aggregate), but `ttt::array` is not.
This leads me to the question, is the compiler allowed to do something here (omitting one ctor call), I am not allowed to do?

And, is there a way around this?

Comment: *"private/deleted ctors are still callable by the user"* has been fixed in C++20 https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9b9Wvn3fj

Comment: An aggregate is, in a sense, transparent to the compiler; the compiler can initialize its members directly, there's no constructor that needs to be called and can do something special. As your class is not an aggregate, the calling code has no choice but to construct a temporary `CLASS` and pass it to `ttt::array` constructor (which then has no choice but to copy or move it into `content`); it can't bypass the constructor and write the `CLASS` instance directly into `content` array. I don't think you can avoid copying without making `ttt::array` an aggregate (which would defeat the point).

Comment: Issue 1 is detected by compiler as warning: https://godbolt.org/z/a6Wobrsqe. IMO proper configuration of compiler is better approach then creating new `array`.

Answer (score 1):

You could package the arguments that should be used to construct the elements in `content` in `std::tuple`s and delay creation of the actual objects until it's time to initialize `content`.

An outline:

```cpp
template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct array {
    template<class... Ts>
    constexpr array(Ts&&... args) :
        content{to_t(std::forward<Ts>(args),
                     std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Ts>::value>())...}
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == N, "wrong number of elements");
    }

private:
    // create one T from a tuple
    template<class... Ts, std::size_t... Idx>
    T to_t(std::tuple<Ts...>&& in, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
        return T{std::forward<Ts>(std::get<Idx>(in))...};
    }

    T content[N];
};
```

Example type to put in an `array`:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    Foo() : a(0.), b(0) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo()\n"; }
    explicit Foo(double A, int B) : a(A), b(B) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(double, int)\n"; }
    Foo(const Foo& o) : a(o.a), b(o.b) { std::cout << "Foo(const Foo&)\n"; }
    Foo(Foo&& o) : a(o.a), b(o.b) { std::cout << "Foo(Foo&&)\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo() {" << a << ", " << b << "}\n"; }

private:
    double a;
    int b;
};
```

You could then create your `array` without copying/moving your `T`:s (guaranteed in C++17, with copy/move elision in C++14, so not guaranteed but probable) by packaging them in `tuple`s. It's a bit cumbersome to type. Hopefully someone else has an idea for how to get around that.

```cpp
int main() {
    Foo f{3.3, 3};
    array<Foo, 4> x(std::forward_as_tuple(1.1, 1),
                    std::forward_as_tuple(),            // default constructor
                    std::forward_as_tuple(2.2, 2),
                    std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(f)) // move constructor
                   );
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/73hYfYxqf)
You can add the compiler option `-fno-elide-constructors` to see that it will move the elements when that optimization is turned off in C++14 mode.

Comment: do I understand correctly that this is something like `emplace_back`, but for all arguments given at once?

Comment: @tommsch Yes, that is what I was aiming for. I think it could be made nicer with a helper function. I'll think more about that and update the answer if I come up with anything